# Multiple GUI Session

Tags: unity, xubuntu

While Ubuntu gives us multiple workspaces but they are not disjoint. The application opened in one workspace can also be seen from another and if accidentally we click it, Ubuntu automatically switches between workspace.

How can I avoid seeing applications opened in another workspace?

Moreover, we can maintain multiple TTY session can't we similarly start multiple GUI session without changing user.

My system has ubtuntu18.04 and unity interface

Comment: I was anware same question exist here https://askubuntu.com/questions/64490/how-can-i-stop-workspaces-from-switching-automatically-to-other-workspaces-when?rq=1